# Does drag+paste count as a valid form of input in Excel?

Tags: discussion, policy, answers, defaults

I recently [answered in Excel](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/78646/44713), where my input was based on the user copying a cell's contents via drag and past over multiple cells, where the input `n` was the final cell to which was dragged, which I thought was acceptable in the question: "*You can get `n` any way.*" yet also "*Standard loopholes are denied.*"

Am I incorrect in assuming that this form of input is valid?

Comment: there are some tags for you :D

Answer (score 5):

## Yes

Since the user input (an integer number) can be found on the left hand column, dragging to the equivalent `n` value for the number of rows is an acceptable form of input.

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of whether this suspicious input method limit should be allowed in general, it is clearly **not** valid for the challenge in question: answers are required to count at least until 2<sup>64</sup>; whereas Excel has a limit of 2<sup>20</sup> rows.

Comment: This should probably have been a comment on the answer (which has now been removed. :P)